# Handles clause requires a WithEvents Callback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, xpo

**Error in CallbackUpdateSchema.Callback**

**BC30506 Visual Basic AND  ASP.net Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. Callback**

[image]

```
Imports DevExpress.Xpo
Imports DevExpress.Data.Filtering
Imports DevExpress.Xpo.DB

Public Class UpdateSchema
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim uow As UnitOfWork

Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    uow = XpoHelper.GetNewUnitOfWork
End Sub

Protected Sub CallbackUpdateSchema_Callback(source As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgs) Handles CallbackUpdateSchema.Callback
    uow.UpdateSchema()
    uow.CreateObjectTypeRecords()
End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UpdateSchema.aspx.vb" %>

<%@  Register assembly="DevExpress.Xpo.v18.2, Version=18.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"  namespace="DevExpress.Xpo" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>   
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButtonUpdateSchema" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Text="Update Schema">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {CallbackUpdateSchema.PerformCallback();}" />
        </dx:ASPxButton>
        <dx:ASPxCallback ID="CallbackUpdateSchema" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="CallbackUpdateSchema">
        </dx:ASPxCallback>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can handle events in a class definition.  Handling of events is usually done by a user of an object.  Is there an overridable property you can use instead?

Comment: i don't think so there is an overridable property i can use.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this class, but is the Init event raised in the constructor?  If so, call MyBase.New and Page_Init in your constructor.  Now I'm curious--can a constructor raise an event?

Answer (score 0):

Use the overridable method OnInit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.oninit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Page_OnInit_System_EventArgs_

Events are meant for users.  For sub-classing, you should use overridable methods instead.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
   MyBase.OnInit()
    uow = XpoHelper.GetNewUnitOfWork
End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou for helping me... but appear error : "Overload resolution failed because no accessible accepts this number of arguments." in text OnInit() and the "Handles clause requires a WithEvents" still error too

Comment: Did you remove sender?

Comment: what it's that?

Comment: The OnMethod overrides don't have a sender parameter like the Method event does.  OnInit only has e.  Also make certain you remove the "handles MyBase.Init" after the subroutine declaration.

Comment: oh, no i'm not remove sender, but still error too:(

Comment: I think I misled you.  I think you needed to use "Handles MyBase.Init" instead of "Me.Init" in your original code.